# Why does JSTL return false positives in null-check of image blob data?

Tags: java, image, jsp, jstl, blob

Both of the following JSTL checks return positive - resulting in the inner message being displayed ("image not null"/"image not empty") - even when the current record does not have an image associated with it.

```
<c:if test="${rec.imgdata != null}">image not null</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty rec.imgdata}">image not empty</c:if>
```

The image is stored as a Blob for each record. What's the correct way to check whether the Blob (`rec.imgdata`) is non-empty?

Comment: What does "empty" mean in the context of a Blob?

Comment: I want to know if the database field contains an image or not. The image is stored as a 'Blob' type. So, yes, exactly, "what does empty mean in the context of a Blob"? Or, put another way, how do you check for the existence of data in the Blob from JSTL? Is that even possible or do I need to write some kind of support function for my model or controller layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Blob` in JSTL. I'd verify beforehand whether the blob is not empty by calling `length()`, and then set the value as request attribute. I.e.:

```
request.setAttribute("showImage", rec.getImgData().length() > 0);
```

if you have more than one `rec` then create a new property `imageAvailable` and call `rec.setImageAvailable(rec.getImgData().length() > 0)`

Have in mind that you can't stream the page AND the image in one response. You only set the path to the image. Which will be a new servlet which will in turn load thh `Blob` and stream it to the client.

Comment: I already have a servlet that displays the images. But I need to know whether to call that servlet or display a holder image if the blob is empty. It's easier to do the check in the JSTL than in a controller or model because it's a list of records and I don't want to manage a separate record to indicate the presence of absence of image data.

Comment: then the first part of my answer should be fine.